# How are subpoena'd documents physically created?

Tags: government, judiciary

I just wondered about the mechanics of how documents requested by subpoena or by congressional inquiry (eg Nadler's current request for Trump-related files from various agencies) are physically created.

Are they photocopied from the originals?  Are the originals themselves handed over?  Do they digitize and email them?

I wondered because I thought it must take some time to do all that photocopying of thousands of pages for multiple requesting parties, if that's what happens, and I can imagine there's some risk to the original document -- eg a photocopier paper jam or papers falling out of sequence or just plain theft.

Comment: This is going to be a very broad answer as it will depend on what is being requested, what format they are originally created in/are currently stored in and for what purpose they are being requested for.

Comment: A friend of mine is a document reviewer, basically his job is to go through all documents turned over during discovery (similar to subpoena) and see which ones are specifically relevant vs not.  And he'll tell you - they turn over the documents in whichever way is *least useful* to the reviewers, so long as they're within the bounds of the law.  Often this means reams of printed out paper. Sometimes it means thousands of PDF files (as images, not as text, so they can't be searched). There's no single standard.